# TensorFlow: generating a random constant

Tags: python, numpy, initialization, tensorflow, interactive-session

In ipython I imported `tensorflow as tf` and `numpy as np` and created an TensorFlow `InteractiveSession`.
When I am running or initializing some normal distribution with numpy input, everything runs fine:

```
some_test = tf.constant(np.random.normal(loc=0.0, scale=1.0, size=(2, 2)))
session.run(some_test)
```

Returns:

```
array([[-0.04152317,  0.19786302],
       [-0.68232622, -0.23439092]])
```

Just as expected.

...but when I use the Tensorflow normal distribution function:

```
some_test = tf.constant(tf.random_normal([2, 2], mean=0.0, stddev=1.0, dtype=tf.float32))
session.run(some_test)
```

...it raises a Type error saying:

```
(...)
TypeError: List of Tensors when single Tensor expected
```

**What am I missing here?**

The output of:

```
sess.run(tf.random_normal([2, 2], mean=0.0, stddev=1.0, dtype=tf.float32))
```

alone returns the exact same thing which `np.random.normal` generates -> a matrix of shape `(2, 2)` with values taken from a normal distribution.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The [`tf.constant()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.7/api_docs/python/constant_op.html#constant) op takes a numpy array (or something implicitly convertible to a numpy array), and returns a [`tf.Tensor`](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.7/api_docs/python/framework.html#Tensor) whose value is the same as that array. It does *not* accept a `tf.Tensor` as its argument.

On the other hand, the `tf.random_normal()` op returns a `tf.Tensor` whose value is generated randomly according to the given distribution each time it runs. Since it returns a `tf.Tensor`, it cannot be used as the argument to `tf.constant()`. This explains the `TypeError` (which is unrelated to the use of `tf.InteractiveSession`, since it occurs when you build the graph).

I'm assuming you want your graph to include a tensor that (i) is randomly generated on its first use, and (ii) constant thereafter. There are two ways to do this:

1. Use NumPy to generate the random value and put it in a `tf.constant()`, as you did in your question:

   ```
   some_test = tf.constant(
       np.random.normal(loc=0.0, scale=1.0, size=(2, 2)).astype(np.float32))
   ```
2. (Potentially faster, as it can use the GPU to generate the random numbers) Use TensorFlow to generate the random value and put it in a `tf.Variable`:

   ```
   some_test = tf.Variable(
       tf.random_normal([2, 2], mean=0.0, stddev=1.0, dtype=tf.float32)
   sess.run(some_test.initializer)  # Must run this before using `some_test`
   ```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation! So I have to use `tf.Variable` when I want the GPU acceleration aka "pure" tensorflow for getting a random "constant"?!

Comment: Yes, it's counterintuitive, isn't it? :) The issue is really that, in TF, the concepts of "is variable" and "is initializable" are combined in the same type - we've occasionally discussed better ways to do initialization (e.g. some equivalent of static initialization in C-like languages), but haven't settled on a design yet. (One could imagine how such a thing would be useful for optimizations like constant folding, etc.)

Comment: Thanks for the response @mrry. If I am trying to do the same thing but I don't want to keep `some_test` constant thereafter would I do the same thing as option 2 but not include `sess.run(some_test.initializer)`?