# TypeError: List of Tensors when single Tensor expected - when using const with tf.random_normal

Tags: python, tensorflow

I have the following TensorFlow code:

```
tf.constant(tf.random_normal([time_step, batch_size], -1, 1))
```

I am getting `TypeError: List of Tensors when single Tensor expected`. Could you tell me what is wrong with the code?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Someone else has answered this question on [another thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35662013/8071521).

Essentially, `tf.constant()` takes a NumPy array as an argument or some sort of array or just a value.

`tf.random_normal()` returns a Tensor which **cannot** be an argument to `tf.constant()`.

To fix this, use `tf.Variable()` instead of `tf.constant()`.

See the answer from the link. The person explains it better.

Comment: But what if you need a constant not a variable?  I mean you know a variable is modified (learned) by the optimizer, and you might not want modification to it, which is why we have constant, because it does not change.  Not being able to use constants might just be a problem, ya know?

Answer (score 2):

`tf.constant` is supposed to have a constant argument - `value`. Here `value` can be a constant value or a list of values of type `dtype`. You can't create a constant tensor that has another tensor as its value.