# Computations (such as tf.greater and tf.cond) on random value tensors not working as expected

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am a tensorflow beginner. According to the [documentation](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/greater), **tf.greater returns the truth value of (x>y) element-wise**

My code is as below:

```
x = tf.random_uniform([])  # Empty array as shape creates a scalar.
y = tf.random_uniform([])
print('x: '+str(x.eval()))
print('y: ' +str(y.eval()))
out = tf.cond(tf.greater(x, y), lambda: x + y, lambda: x - y)
print(sess.run(tf.greater(x, y)))
print(sess.run(out))
```

The output I got is:

```
x: 0.79379404
y: 0.30891895
False
0.3438499
```

x is bigger than y so it should return True and x+y should be 1.10271299
why is my expected output different than the actual output?

Answer (score 2):

The tricky part with `tensorflow` is that the code is used to build a graph of computations, which can then be ran/evaluated in a `tf.Session`.

In your example, at each evaluation, random tensors `x` and `y` are generated.

- So, your call `x.eval()` generates random tensors `x` and `y`.
- Your call `y.eval()` regenerates random tensors `x` and `y`.
- And so do `sess.run(tf.greater(x, y))` and `sess.run(out)`.

Therefore, your prints of `x` and `y` do not reflect the actual `x` and `y` used in `sess.run(tf.greater(x, y))` and `sess.run(out)` (which by the way also explains why your result `0.3438499` do not correspond to neither `x+y` or `x-y`).

By freezing tensors `x` and `y` to `tf.constant`, you get the expected behaviour:

```
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf

with tf.Session() as sess:
   x = tf.constant(np.random.uniform())
   y = tf.constant(np.random.uniform())
   print('x: '+str(x.eval()))
   print('y: '+str(y.eval()))
   out = tf.cond(tf.greater(x, y), lambda: x + y, lambda: x - y)
   print(sess.run(tf.greater(x, y)))
   print(sess.run(out))
```

*prints (on one run on my side)*

```
x: 0.75513345
y: 0.04605962
True
0.80119306
```

Comment: when I try to create x = tf.constant(tf.random_uniform([])) it raises the error TypeError: List of Tensors when single Tensor expected, can I know why? because I am not familiar with creating random uniform tensor with numpy

Comment: The question has been asked and answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44206767/typeerror-list-of-tensors-when-single-tensor-expected-when-using-const-with-t

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing wrong with `tf.greater` or `tf.cond`. But since the two have been executed in different session runs, the values sampled from `x` and `y` will be different in each one. This can be noticed by fetching `x` and `y` alongside the output:

```
x = tf.random_uniform([])
y = tf.random_uniform([])
g = tf.greater(x, y)      # you can also do `x > y`, same TF op
c = tf.cond(g, lambda: x + y, lambda: x - y)
sess = tf.Session()
sess.run([x, y, g])
sess.run([x, y, c])
```

The output:

```
[0.11019015, 0.028247476, True]
[0.29905212, 0.9846852, -0.68563306]
```

In order to ensure that these operations use the same value, you can perform both operations in the same run:

```
sess.run([x, y, g, c])
```

```
[0.74283457, 0.8982569, False, -0.15542233]
```

Or turn `x` and `y` into TensorFlow variables, which would retain the same numbers from the distribution until the next reassignment.

```
x = tf.get_variable('x', shape=[], initializer=tf.random_uniform_initializer())
y = tf.get_variable('y', shape=[], initializer=tf.random_uniform_initializer())

g = x > y
c = tf.cond(g, lambda: x + y, lambda: x - y)

reset_vars = tf.variables_initializer([x, y])

sess = tf.Session()
sess.run(reset_vars) # this must be called once
sess.run([x, y, g])
sess.run([x, y, c])
```

```
[0.4862318, 0.48253357, True]
[0.4862318, 0.48253357, 0.9687654]
```